# Simply connected imply any two paths are freely homotopic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know that simply connected ($\pi_0(p)=0$ and path-connected) is equivalent to "the space is path-connected and any two paths with the same endpoints are homotopic". What about two paths with different endpoints? Does simply connectedness implies this?

My attempt: I can join the endpoints of two paths $\gamma_1, \gamma_2: [0,1] \to X$ by the path-connecteness assumpion. By being simply connected, I get a contractible loop, with $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ being in its boundary. This should imply they are homotopic but I'm not sure how to prove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any two paths in a path-connected space are freely homotopic.

To see this let $\gamma: x \rightarrow y$ and $\gamma‘:x‘\rightarrow y‘$ be two paths. Let $z$ be an arbitrary point and fix paths $\rho:z\rightarrow x$ and $\rho‘:z\rightarrow x‘$.

Then we can give a free homotopy $\gamma \sim \gamma‘$ by

1. contracting $\gamma$ to the constant path at $x$
2. moving this constant path along $\rho^{-1}$ and then $\rho$ to the constant path at $x‘$
3. inflating the constant path at $x‘$ to be $\gamma‘$ (doing the reverse to the analogue of 1)

This is the reason, why homotopy relative endpoints / a subspace is really important for getting useful invariants!

Ps: Please don’t make me parametrize this.

Comment: You can generalize this: Any two maps $f, g: C\to X$ on a contractible $C$ are homotopic if $X$ is path-connected.

Comment: That is very likely. What do you have in mind specifically?

Comment: It is just a comment, you need not extend your answer. In fact $f,g$ are homotopic to constant maps, and all constant maps are homotopic.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, no need to parametrize ;p I think Paul's statement is proved in the same way that you just did, the image of $f$ can be contracted to a point because contractibility is preserved under continuous functions.

Comment: @PaulFrost sorry, I only could see the „you can generalize this“ part of your comment, which was kind of a tautology. It does make more sense now, thanks :)